# Print out cell location (e.g. E3) in message box

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I am iterating from E2 to E15. I want to show a message box and indicate the cell in it. For example is E3 is empty, I want the error to be Please fill in cell E3. I am using the code below. How shall it be changed?

```
        Set rRng = Sheet1.Range("E2:E15")
        For Each c In rRng.Cells
            If c.Value = "" Then
                      MsgBox ("Please fill in cell" + c)
                      GoTo end_of_for
            End If
        Next
        end_of_for:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so, using the address property of a range. If you have only one blank you can avoid a loop using specialcells. Note that the concatenator is & rather than +.

```
Set rRng = Sheet1.Range("E2:E15")
For Each c In rRng.Cells
    If c.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please fill in cell " & c.Address
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

use SpecialCells to avoid the loop:

```
If Application.CountA(Sheet1.Range("E2:E15")) <> Sheet1.Range("E2:E15").Cells.Count Then
    Set rrng = Sheet1.Range("E2:E15").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    If Not rrng Is Nothing Then MsgBox "Please fill in cell(s): " & rrng.Address(0, 0)
End If
```

This will return the address of all the blank cells at once.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can get the adresse in the form "$E$2" by calling the method .Address on the Cells object. By replacing the '$' character, you can get what you want

```
Set rRng = Range("E2:E15")
For Each c In rRng.Cells
    If c.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox ("Please fill in cell " + Replace(c.Address, "$", ""))
        GoTo end_of_for
    End If
Next
end_of_for:
```

Comment: Or you can just use the criteria for Address: `c.Address(0,0)` which makes the address relative(without the `$`).